# How to guess http encoding with node.js?

Tags: http, node.js, encoding

When I'm getting this page `http://booking.airasia.com/css/AKBase/Cultures/en-GB/far-min.css` with node's `http`, the `toString` method gives me corrupt stuff. Apparently that page is in `UTF-16`, but there is no mention of that fact in headers. Firefox however has no problems guessing the encoding, is this something node can do?

(I know I can convert this specific page, since I know its encoding *now*, but I want to guess the encoding)

Comment: Try using the [`request`](https://npmjs.org/package/request) module. It may have some logic in it to guess encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ex-colleague of mine ported python chardet to javascript: https://github.com/aadsm/jschardet